# Как сделать onClick(); в Fragment

Tags: android, android-on-click

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой у меня есть Дерево с большим количеством подпунктов и мне нужно что бы при нажатии на подпункт открывался xml файл то есть раньше я кнопку делал onClick и уже в Activity указывал public void onClick(View v) а сейчас у меня есть только Fragment в котором нужно сделать переход в xml файл

```
private void fillFolder(TreeNode folder) {

//1

    TreeNode currentNode1 = folder;
    for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
        TreeNode file = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_flammable_materials, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.B_I_1_1)));
        currentNode1.addChild(file);
        currentNode1 = file;

//1.1

        TreeNode file1 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.B_I_1_2)));
        currentNode1.addChild(file1);
        currentNode1 = file;
```

Нужно что бы Gunpowder(Hawk) был кликабельный и перекидывал на xml файл

[image: scrn]

Comment: Что вы понимаете под открываться? Открываться как страница, или должно появиться ниже выбранного item блок?

Comment: Как страница. То есть при нажатии открывалась указанная страница.

Comment: xml, это activity или fragment?

Comment: xml на который нужно перейти  activity

Comment: создаете Intent с выбранным Activity и передаете его в startActivity.
Наподобии вот этого Intent intent = new Intent(HelloWorld.this, AboutActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Выдало ошибку cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.nameProject.ui.items.fragment.TwoDScrollingArrowExpandFragment, java.lang.Class<com.exampl.nameProject.ui.activity_keys.custom_k.customs_k_1>)'

Comment: @Karpuha, это значит, что у вас фрагмент, а не активити. Вам надо понять разницу между активити и фрагментом и разметкой. В андроиде фразы типа "xml на который нужно перейти" - не имеют смысла. Раз у вас фрагмент - ищите в сети как один фрагмент заменить другим. Или задайте вопрос/измените этот указав, что у вас именно фрагмент.